# Changing Alert message to display in the div on Google Map Geocoding service search

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to change Alert message(alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);) to be displayed in the div on Google Map Geocoding service search. What is the best way to do this?

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple

```
var geocoder;
var map;
function initialize() {
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: latlng
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
}

function codeAddress() {
  var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
  geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          position: results[0].geometry.location
      });
    } else {
      alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
    }
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: I tried $(".errormapsearch").fadeIn(); at where alert is but did not work. I guess jQuery is not working in Google Map API?

Comment: JQuery has nothing to do with the Google Maps API, did you include the library on your page?

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific about "to DOM on Google Map Geocoding service search"? What does that mean; what do you want to achieve?

Comment: @ZsoltSafrany I wanted to have Error message in DIV instead of alert. Ended up coming up with below code. I guess it can be more cleaner? Thank you for the comment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var geocoder;
var map;
function initialize() {
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: latlng
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
}

function codeAddress() {
  var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
  geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          position: results[0].geometry.location
      });

      // Remove Div if Error message exist on the page
      var elem = document.getElementById("lsError");
      if (elem) {
          elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
      }

    } else {
      //alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);

      // Add error message in the div id=lsError
      if (!document.getElementById("lsError")) {
          var node = document.createElement("div");
          node.id = "lsError";              
          var textnode = document.createTextNode("Please Enter Zipcode or City");        
          node.appendChild(textnode);
          document.getElementById("searchLocation").appendChild(node); 
      }



    }
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

with CSS for error message.

```
<style>
  #searchLocation{
    position: relative;
  }
  #lsError{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -20px;
    background: red;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px; 
  }
</style>
```

So I ended up using Javascript to create error message in Div. Seems like it works.